# Problems accessing model relationship Eloquent Model Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm an early stage Laravel developer (learning) and I've run into some trouble when working with relationships amongst Eloquent models. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Creating a sites with a bunch of recipes and I am currently working on separating different views based on categories (breakfast, lunch, dinner etc.). In the views, each recipe can displays the recipe title and the creator of the recipe. I have a User model, Recipe model, and Category model. In my breakfast.blade.php view, I'm trying to access $recipe->category->name in an @if statement in order to sort out the relevant recipes. It throws me an error and says that "Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance". 
My code from controllers, views, and models are posted below:

Recipe Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recipe extends Model
{
//Table Name
protected $table = 'recipes';
// Primary Key
public $primaryKey = 'id';
// Timestamps
public $timestamps = true;

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
}

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
}
```

Category model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
protected $table = 'categories';

public function recipes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recipe');
}
}
```

Top part of CategoryController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Recipe;
use App\Category;
use App\User;
use App\Auth;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
public function showBreakfast(){
    $recipes = Recipe::all();
    $users = User::all();
    return view('recipes.categories.breakfast')->with('recipes', 
 $recipes);
}
```

And the beginning of my @if statement and @foreach loop (this is where the error is thrown)

```
@section('content')
<section>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
@if(count($recipes) > 0 && $recipes->category->name == 'Breakfast') 
@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
```

I would be so grateful for any help! I've been messing around with controllers, Eloquent models, and passing through variables to views and sometimes I get it to work and sometimes I don't. I don't seem to understand the underlying rules for how to use this efficiently. Once again, I am very grateful for any help! :) Let me know if I need to clarify the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `all()` method you receive the whole collection from that model. The `$recipes` variable is a array of objects (recipes), not just one object(recipe), so you should use a foreach to access the category name from each recipe :

```
@if(count($recipes) > 0)
    @foreach($recipes as $recipe) 
        @if($recipe->category->name == 'Breakfast') 
        // do something
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

You make a mistake in your relations

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

You should pass the foreign key as the second parameter, not the id.

Also, you forgot to mention which attributes are fillable:

```
$fillable = ['name',...

]
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your quick response! I made those changes but it doesn't fix the error :( I still get "Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance" and it is referring to the $recipes->category->name in my @if statement. What do you think I can do?

Comment: Yes. I've tried doing this solution too and it give me "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::category does not exist". The method does exist... Another strange thing is if I simply run my @foreach loop with $recipes as $recipe and have them print out, I can then access $recipe->category->name.. Why do you think that is?

Comment: You used my if statament or yours? In your first comment you used your if, not mine

Comment: Thats what i told you in my answer, you cannot use the relation in a array of objects, you should use a foreach to access each category name from each recipe. The  category relation is for one object, not the entire collection. That's why its giving this error.

Comment: Ohh now I understand! That is great, it works very well now! Thank you for your help! I misunderstood the first time! Thanks!! :)

Comment: I'm glad i could help, friend :). Don't forget to include the foreign key in your relation!!